# how can i run a script containing shell escape from ipython?

Tags: python, ipython

It's so convenient to use shell escape from interactive environment in ipython, but is it possible to call python script containing shell escape from ipython?

Comment: May you please give an example of the script you are trying to invoke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give the script a `.ipy` extension, ipython's special syntax (like `!ls`) should work when you do `ipython myscript.ipy`.